# Text Over Round Image

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

I want to put a large text over a round image with background image.

Like this:  [image]

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Comment: Do you just need to show the text on the phone, or is the image supposed to be saved?

Comment: You just need a TextView with a round shapedrawable as its background.

Comment: Try using android Glide to make it circular.

Comment: @ArbazRizvi You don't need an extra library for such a trivial task

Answer (score 5):

Try this:
Create a `xml` file in drawable folder: `circular_bg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="oval">

   <solid android:color="#B72854" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp" />
   <size
        android:width="15dp"
        android:height="15dp" />
</shape>
```

Then add this line in your `TextView` background:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="FB"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="@drawable/circular_bg"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>
```

It will help you. :)

Comment: This is the correct answer! People are actually using libraries for this LOL

Answer (score 2):

Best way to used Button and set background drawable look.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">

<solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

</shape>
```

After set this drawable button background and set text.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:text="FB"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="35sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways,

if you are actually using a graphic image, use a relative layout and place the image view and textview as a child of it. And make sure you keep the textview with the `centerInParent` parameter.

if you do not need a graphic asset, you can create a custom drawable, and set that as a background to your textview.

The custom drawable can be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="28dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/THEME_GREEN_DARK" />
</shape>
```

and then you can just add it as a background to your textview. also, change your radius as per the size of circle you need!

Answer (score 1):

There are so many libs to do that

add this to build.gradle

```
repositories{
    maven {
        url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
}
```

[image]

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="60dp"
           android:layout_height="60dp"
           android:id="@+id/image_view"/>
```

Note: Specify width/height for the ImageView and the drawable will auto-scale to fit the size.

```
TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
                .buildRect("FB", Color.RED);

ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. Thanks

circular_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<solid
android:color="#ff1e8f" />

<size
android:width="120dp"
android:height="120dp" />

<corners
android:bottomLeftRadius="65dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="65dp"
android:topLeftRadius="65dp"
android:topRightRadius="65dp" />

</shape>
```

layout.xml

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:background="@drawable/circular_drawable"
android:gravity="center"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:text="FB"
android:textSize="26sp"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```